# How to determine if multiple numbers are odd or even in C debug

Tags: c, debugging

All my if else statements work but when I try to enter in an odd number and then an even number following it I keep getting "Both numbers are even."
I've tried everything and I'm totally confused as to why my code fails when faced with an even number than odd like: 21 22

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

  int x;
  int y;
  printf("Enter two numbers:\n");
  scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);

  if (x,y % 2  == 0)
      printf("Both numbers are even.",x,y);

  else if (x % 2 == 0)
      printf("The first number is even.", x);

  else if (y % 2 == 0)
     printf("The second number is even.", y);

  else
      printf("Both numbers are odd.");


      return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think will `x,y % 2  == 0` do? It does not even work in languages which allow for tuples like Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C the comma operator evaluates its first argument and discards the result, then evaluates the second argument and returns it.

So if `x` is `21` and `y` is `22` then the expression `x,y` will evaluate to `22`.  `x` is evaluated to `21` and discarded and `y` is evaluated to `22` and returned.  And of course `22 % 2 == 0` is true.  So that condition will fire and will print out `Both numbers are even.`.

Your condition needs to be `((x % 2 == 0) && (y % 2 == 0))`

Also, if you actually want to print out the number(s) you'll need to put something like `%d` (or two of them in the "Both numbers" cases) in those `printf()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

even if you use `(x,y)%2==0` then also it is similar to `y%2==0`

use `if((x%2==0) && (y%2==0))`
and `%d` inside `printf(" ");`